# Create new column with values in long format pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to calculate the vote share for a candidate in a particular district for a particular election.

I've got a dataset that gives me the party of the candidate, the district that they ran in, and the year of the election.

However, I have their competitors as well and want to calculate the vote share for one of the candidates, say the Democratic candidate. How would I then place that vote share value in the rows for all of those in that particular race?

Here's an example of a pandas dataframe that I have:

```
   year    state  district                   candidate       party  candidatevotes  totalvotes
0  1976  alabama         1              BILL DAVENPORT    DEMOCRAT           58906      157170 
1  1976  alabama         1                JACK EDWARDS  REPUBLICAN           98257      157170 
2  1976  alabama         1                     WRITEIN         NaN               7      157170
3  1976  alabama         2             J CAROLE KEAHEY    DEMOCRAT           66288      156362
4  1976  alabama         2  WILLIAM L "BILL" DICKINSON  REPUBLICAN           90069      156362
```

What I want to be able to do is have a column that would take the vote share of the democratic candidate for that particular district and year. But that vote share value be there for all of the candidates in that particular race:

```
   year    state  district                   candidate       party  candidatevotes  totalvotes    Dem_vote_share
0  1976  alabama         1              BILL DAVENPORT    DEMOCRAT           58906      157170    0.374
1  1976  alabama         1                JACK EDWARDS  REPUBLICAN           98257      157170    0.374
2  1976  alabama         1                     WRITEIN         NaN               7      157170    0.374
3  1976  alabama         2             J CAROLE KEAHEY    DEMOCRAT           66288      156362    0.424
4  1976  alabama         2  WILLIAM L "BILL" DICKINSON  REPUBLICAN           90069      156362    0.424
```

If helpful: a full dataset can be found here: https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/IG0UN2

EDIT:

For the full dataset, this is what ended up working:

```
df['Unique_District'] = df[['state', 'district']].apply(lambda x: '-'.join(x.astype(str)), axis=1) #to make a unique district column

mapping_vals = (
    df[df['party'].eq('DEMOCRAT')]
    .set_index(['year', 'Unique_District'])
    .apply(lambda x: x['candidatevotes']/x['totalvotes'],axis=1)
    .groupby(level=[0,1]).sum()
)

df['Dem_vote_share'] = df.set_index(['year', 'Unique_District']).index.map(mapping_vals)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter your df for the kind of party you want. Then get the `Dem_votes_share` and map its results to the df.

New Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': [1976, 1976, 1980, 1980, 1976, 1976, 1980, 1980], 
    'state': ['alabama',  'alabama',  'alaska',  'alaska',  'alabama',  'alabama',  'alaska',  'alaska'], 
    'district': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
    'candidate': ['BILL DAVENPORT',  'JACK EDWARDS',  'WRITEIN',  'foo',  'J CAROLE KEAHEY',  'WILLIAM L "BILL" DICKINSON',  'foo2',  'foo3'], 
    'party': ['DEMOCRAT',  'DEMOCRAT',  'DEMOCRAT',  'REPUBLICAN',  'DEMOCRAT',  'REPUBLICAN',  'DEMOCRAT',  'REPUBLICAN'], 
    'candidatevotes': [58906, 98257, 50000, 20000, 66288, 90069, 10000, 20000], 
    'totalvotes': [157163, 157163, 70000, 70000, 156362, 156362, 30000, 30000]
})
bigprint(df)

   year    state  district                   candidate       party  candidatevotes  totalvotes
0  1976  alabama         1              BILL DAVENPORT    DEMOCRAT           58906      157163
1  1976  alabama         1                JACK EDWARDS    DEMOCRAT           98257      157163
2  1980   alaska         1                     WRITEIN    DEMOCRAT           50000       70000
3  1980   alaska         1                         foo  REPUBLICAN           20000       70000
4  1976  alabama         2             J CAROLE KEAHEY    DEMOCRAT           66288      156362
5  1976  alabama         2  WILLIAM L "BILL" DICKINSON  REPUBLICAN           90069      156362
6  1980   alaska         2                        foo2    DEMOCRAT           10000       30000
7  1980   alaska         2                        foo3  REPUBLICAN           20000       30000
```

```
mapping_vals = (
    df[df['party'].eq('DEMOCRAT')]
    .set_index(['year', 'district'])
    .apply(lambda x: x['candidatevotes']/x['totalvotes'],axis=1)
    .groupby(level=[0,1]).sum()
)
print(mapping_vals)

year  district
1976  1           1.000000
      2           0.423939
1980  1           0.714286
      2           0.333333
dtype: float64


df['Dem_vote_share'] = df.set_index(['year', 'district']).index.map(mapping_vals)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   year    state  district                   candidate       party  candidatevotes  totalvotes  Dem_vote_share
0  1976  alabama         1              BILL DAVENPORT    DEMOCRAT           58906      157163        1.000000
1  1976  alabama         1                JACK EDWARDS    DEMOCRAT           98257      157163        1.000000
2  1980   alaska         1                     WRITEIN    DEMOCRAT           50000       70000        0.714286
3  1980   alaska         1                         foo  REPUBLICAN           20000       70000        0.714286
4  1976  alabama         2             J CAROLE KEAHEY    DEMOCRAT           66288      156362        0.423939
5  1976  alabama         2  WILLIAM L "BILL" DICKINSON  REPUBLICAN           90069      156362        0.423939
6  1980   alaska         2                        foo2    DEMOCRAT           10000       30000        0.333333
7  1980   alaska         2                        foo3  REPUBLICAN           20000       30000        0.333333
```

Comment: So the example df I had was not a great one, this dataset includes different years and different states. So I can have district 1 in Alabama in 2012 or can have district 1 in Alaska. Would I need to change the set_index part to do that?

Comment: I changed input a bit and tried again. Better now?

Comment: It is working on the toy dataset you gave me. However, on my complete dataset it's telling throwing an error with the part where I apply the mapping to my dataframe `Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index Objects`. So it sounds like there's something weird there...

Comment: Could this possibly be because technically in some districts you could have two Democratic candidates facing each other? Would I maybe place an ifelse statement to just give those sorts of districts a value of 1?

Comment: What would you want to do if there are two democrats in one district facing each other? If I change the 2nd row in `party` in my dataset, I can simulate the same error you get. ( 2 democrats in 1976 in district 1 in alabama). `map` will fail because there is no distinct row for `1976` and `alabama`. I don't have access on the original data, otherwise I would have tested it on there.

Comment: If there are two democrats facing one another, it'd be a value of 1. But if say the general election had like 2 democrats and 1 republican, then it'd be the Dem_cand_1 + Dem_cand_2/totalvoteshare. [link to original data](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/IG0UN2)

Comment: If I understand that right, we just need to aggregate by sum the Series of `mapping_vals` to make them unique again. Then it should work right? Since we build the division by the total votes we already included different parties....only need to sum the ratio of all democrats. As I said, I dont have access to the data, it is denied without filling in some information about my company.

Comment: I updated the answer, have a look at the bottom

Comment: Yeah, that sounds right. Do you have the code for how you'd do that? I'd just change the mapping_vals object to be `.apply(lambda x: x['candidatevotes'/x['totalvotes'],axis=1].aggregate()` right?

Comment: Yes, that works. One slight change, but it won't let me edit your answer. For my full dataset, before I used the code in your answer, I needed to combine the state and district columns because it was essentially only grouping by the district and then applying all of it across all states. So what I did beforehand was create a unique state-district column: `df['Unique_District'] = df[['state', 'district']].apply(lambda x: '-'.join(x.astype(str)), axis=1). THEN I ran what you have. 

That's what ended up doing it for me.

Comment: Glad to hear that! No need to change as long as you get what you want :) you can thank me by accepting the answer as solved.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `transform()` with a custom function. You can try with:

```
df['Dem_votes_share'] = df.groupby('party')['candidatevotes'].transform(lambda x: sum(x)/df['candidatevotes'].sum())
```

Following an mock-up example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['party'] = ['D','R','NULL','D','R']
df['candidatevotes'] = [58906,98257,7,66288,90069]
df['candidate'] = ['Bill','Jack','Writein','J Carole','William L']
```

We get:

```
  party  candidatevotes  candidate  Dem_votes_share
0     D           58906       Bill         0.399309
1     R           98257       Jack         0.600669
2  NULL               7    Writein         0.000022
3     D           66288   J Carole         0.399309
4     R           90069  William L         0.600669
```

Comment: That gives me vote share for the candidates of a particular party for that race, no? How would I adjust this to give me instead the vote share for the Democrats in that particular race? And put that value in the row for their Republican competitor?